# All SE Inbox and Rep buttons keep sending me to login page

Tags: bug, status-completed

```
Windows 7 x64
FF 59.0.2 x64
uBlock disabled
```

Clicking on either:

[image]

Sends me to:

[image]

Console log upon clicking Inbox:

[image]

Comment: Is JavaScript not running or failing to load in your browser? Any console errors? Both of those go to pages on stackexchange.com if the script that gives you the popup isn't running. You're just not logged in on that site (it doesn't use the global cookie that logs you into all sites).

Comment: @animuson: I'm having the same problem. I was just writing a bug report myself but I got distracted by a slightly related complaint about the same thing. The script works just fine on the main site - I'm only experiencing this on meta.

Comment: Ah interesting. Yes, I can repro on Meta sites.

Comment: @animuson I added a console log screenshot

Comment: All the menu buttons are borked for me, on both meta and the main site.

Comment: Repro'd on Meta, on the latest Google Chrome.

Comment: @Gimby Borkness confirmed for all my StackExchange sites.

Comment: Fix incoming...

Comment: I hate to admit it but it has been unduly stressful to keep getting inbox messages and not being able to click my Inbox :(

Comment: Latest chrome Mac OS clicking on link takes me to stackexchange network profile equivalent link and error console looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CPPV.png

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is doing you good as you have to suffer both this and a serial downvoting spree all at once ;)

Comment: Mandatory link to the MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309478/245360

Comment: @Gimby it has truly been a roller-coaster of emotions at a theme park named Sharknado

Comment: It seems to be working again :-)

Comment: For me it's still buggy (Stackexchange, click on Inbox, get redirected).

Comment: False alarm, it's broken again

Comment: Ok, working now

Comment: This stress is not good for me. I need another drink...

Comment: Clicking on the "Achievements" nav item takes me to https://stackexchange.com/users/2809239?tab=reputation

Comment: @JAL mine works, for now...

Comment: @Gimby I'm pretty sure that all the downvotes I got caused some sort of overflow that affected everyone's notification bar.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus maybe stop drinking at this point.

Comment: @Gimby that suggestion sounds a bit extreme, don't you think?

Comment: Woo, I was afraid this was a "new feature".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Joey from the show "Friends" saying "Very, VERY sorry"]

Comment: Hurray it's fixed :)