# Is a meme an answer?

Tags: discussion, meta, not-an-answer

Consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366634/6471538) Meta answer from @balpha ♦:

> [image: Joey from the show "Friends" saying "Very, VERY sorry"]

This was literally his entire answer. I flagged this meme-only answer as Not An Answer (NAA). My flag was declined:

> not an answer – Robert Columbia 23 hours ago   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Are answers such as these which consist of nothing more than a meme actually answers?

In this case, it's not clear what @balpha ♦ was trying to say with the meme - it seems that he may have intended to imply that he had caused the bug, fixed it, and was apologizing, but it could also have been the case that he was simply posting a social "sorry" that would literally be nothing more than an NAA comment, as if someone had posted an "answer" to a C++ question by saying "Sorry you are having so much trouble with C++".

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Answer (score 18):

It's a bug report. The only real answers to such a thing are:

1. Here's a detailed list of what went wrong, and we're moving forward to correct it.
2. We did something small/stupid/both, and have fixed the problem in 3 minutes.
3. Reasons why it isn't a bug.

From the context, it seems to me that #2 is in play here: it's not something worth detailing specifically what went wrong, and it's been fixed.

While I would generally say that an image macro isn't a good answer, in cases like this, I would say that it adequately gets the point across: there was an issue, and it isn't an issue anymore.